# connect-multiparty express file is getting stored on local

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data

I am trying to create backend service api's to upload files to the azure blob storage using azure vm.
I created a node-js express app. I am trying to parse the file body using connect-multiparty, but it is storing file in local which I dont want. How can I get body in the code.

Thanks in advance.